# use integrated database in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am making an application in ionic. I'm trying to create a mobile app. now I get a web request ($http) with more than 17000 records JSON objects. I can not use localStorage to store them. then I decided to use an application such as SQLite, or minimongo. I recommend that tool to integrate into my application ?. 
I want to optimize the management of more than 17 thousand json I get objects.

Comment: Do you need all that data at the same time? The recommended would be make some pagination and load data as you need it.

Comment: @ItaloAyres I mean a little more. I need to have at the same time that much information. I give you a have in 17000 records every country in the world example, and would like to show each country's production as fishing, also in those 17000 records can also have other production such as harvesting, as you will see it is necessary to load all . my question is, which tool can be used to store this information and not simply have a json with 17000 records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could send all 17,000 JSON objects back, but that extremely inefficient and I don't recommend doing that. There is no tool that is going to speed up a gigantic HTTP request like this.

Do you have to have all of them at the same time? A better way would be to implement some sort of pagination and dynamically load the data that you need. Twitter is a perfect example: Imagine if Twitter loaded your entire feed, all the way back to when you first created your account? That would be an immense amount of data. Rather, it loads the first 50 tweets or so, and uses infinite scroll to dynamically load the tweets as you scroll down.

This requires making an HTTP request for each new page of data that you need. With something like this in Angular, I'm guessing you are making use of ng-repeat, which has very large performance issues when it comes to displaying a lot of data at once like this. Just another argument for paginating :)

Comment: I mean a little more. I need to have at the same time that much information. I give you a have in 17000 records every country in the world example, and would like to show each country's production as fishing, also in those 17000 records can also have other production such as harvesting, as you will see it is necessary to load all . my question is, which tool can be used to store this information and not simply have a json with 17000 records.